# Kendo grid auto-edit, auto-save works but field value reverts in UI

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In a Kendo grid (v2013.3) I want to auto-save a row when the user moves to a different row.  So I code the change event, which fires when the row selection is changed, to call grid.saveChanges().  Then I re-select the row that we changed to (because the saveChanges seems to have canceled the row selection.) Finally, I call grid.editRow(row) so that the new row will be in edit mode.

This almost works fine.  When the user changes a value in a row A, then clicks away to row B,  the save action properly occurs and the web app sees the changed value.  However, the UI itself reverts to the old value.  This occurs because of the call to grid.editRow().

I suspect that Kendo is doing a cancel behind the scenes, even though the changed data is already saved.

Suggestions on how to address this problem?  Here's the change handler:

```
 ViLinking.gridItemSelected = function (e) {

        var row = ViLinking.getSingleSelectedRow(this);
        if (row == null) {
            return;
        }
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(row);
        if (dataItem == ViLinking.currentDataItem) {
            return;
        }
        // apparently the row reference does not survive saveChanges() so prepare to re-get it. 
        ViLinking.currentDataItem = dataItem;
        var dataUid = row.attributes["data-uid"];
        var table = $(row).closest("table");
        ViLinking.setKendoUpdateContentType(this);
        this.saveChanges();
        row = table.find('tr[data-uid="' + dataUid.value + '"]');
        this.select(row);
        this.editRow(row);
    };
```

Here's the part of the view that generates the table (it's a child table)

```
<script id="ViDetailsTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<VendItemProxyForUi>()
          .Name("details_#=ItemOid#")
          .Columns(cs =>
              {
                  cs.Bound(c => c.ItemOid).Hidden();
                  cs.Bound(c => c.VendorItemID);
                  cs.Bound(c => c.IsSplit);
                  cs.Bound(c => c.VendorItemName);
                  cs.Bound(c => c.VendorItemPackSize);
                  cs.Bound(c => c.IsCatchweight);
                  cs.Bound(c => c.IsApproved);
                  cs.Bound(c => c.UofMOidForUi).EditorTemplateName("UofmDdTemplate");//.ClientTemplate("#=UofMName#");
                  cs.Bound(c => c.UofMName);
                  cs.Command(command =>
                      {
                          command.Edit();
                          command.Destroy();
                      }).Width(200);
              }
          )
          .Selectable()
          .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .DataSource(ds => ds
                                .Ajax()
                                .Model(mdl =>
                                    {
                                        mdl.Id(vi => vi.VendorItemID);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.VendorItemID).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.VendorItemName).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.IsSplit).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.IsCatchweight).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.DiscontinueDate).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.IsRestricted).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.VendorItemPackSize).Editable(false);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.IsApproved).Editable(true);
                                        mdl.Field(f => f.UofMName).Editable(true);
                                    }
                                )
                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetVisForGi", "ViLinkingWorksheet", new { _msk = Model.MultiSessionKey, itemOid="#=ItemOid#"}))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("SyncModelFromUi", "ViLinkingWorksheet", new { _msk = Model.MultiSessionKey, itemOid="#=ItemOid#", delete=false}))
                                .Destroy(update => update.Action("SyncModelFromUi", "ViLinkingWorksheet", new { _msk = Model.MultiSessionKey, itemOid="#=ItemOid#",delete=true}))
          )


          //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100px;" })
          .Events(ev =>
              {
                  ev.Change("ViLinking.gridItemSelected");
                  ev.Cancel("ViLinking.saveOnCancel");
              })
          //.Navigatable()
          .ToClientTemplate())

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the view code and related controller actions?

Comment: I'll edit my post to add some code, but I do think that this snippet is all that's relevant, if you'll believe me that 1) this JS code is invoked by the change event and 2) the controller method is a stub that returns null.  Also, the behavior is fine if I click the kendo <update> button while on the row.  It's just the case of invoking edit on a different row that makes the failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
1- View

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<User>()
        .Name("GridName")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            ...
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 }))
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
        .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .PageSize(20)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(a => a.Id);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Users"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Users"))
          )
          .Events(events => events.Save("SaveChanges"))
            )

        <script>
          function SaveChanges() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.sync();
                });
        </script>

2- Controller

    public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<User> models)
            {
                if (models != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (models.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var item in models)
                        {
                            Update(item); // Find item in database, modify the properties of the object & save change in database
                        }
                    }
                }

                return Json(models.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
            }
```